# Splitting a string with delimiters and retrieve whitespace if one delimiter follows another

Tags: regex, split

I am sorry if this is a duplicate - but I couldn't find any related question. (maybe I just can't find the right search expression for this kind of problem)

Think of the following string in **Java**:

```
"test:test2+test3++test4:test5+test6"
```

As you can see the delimiters are `:` and `+`.

Using the Apache `StringUtils.split(string, "[:+]")` Method works fine for splitting, but the problem is that if `++` appears the returned `StringArray` does not contain a whitespace for indicating that there is a not used value.

This means I would need the following output:

```
 "test"  
 "test2"  
 "test3"  
 " " <-- whitespace!  
 "test4"  
 "test5"  
 "test6"
```

The `++` can also appear at the start or end of the string.
Is there a way to fix this with a regular expression?

Comment: Shame on me I overlooked that: StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens is also a solution for my question.

Comment: Late note: This is also achievable through String.split(), if the following parameters are used `someString.split("\\+", -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
String string = "test:test2+test3++test4:test5+test6";
string.replaceAll("([:+]){2,}", "$1 $1").split("[:+]")
```

**OUTPUT:**

1. test
2. test2
3. test3
4. " "
5. test4
6. test5
7. test6

See token # 4 with space (I added quotes to demonstrate).

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! Thats just what I was looking for. :) Could you explain why the replaceAll method is necessary (and what its actually doing since I am not a regexp expert)? Would be a great help! ;)

Comment: Yes sure. `replaceAll` is finding 2 or more of `+ OR :` and inserting a space between them, see `$1 $1` where `$1` is matched group #1. And rest is simple split operation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
 String s = "test:test2+test3++test4:test5++test6";
String[] s1 = s.replaceAll ("[:+]{1}", " ").split (" ");

for(int i = 0;i<s1.length;i++){
    System.out.println (s1[i]);
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
 test
 test2
 test3

 test4
 test5

 test6
```

Comment: Hello Adarsh, first of all thanks for your answer. The output you describe is the same output as StringUtils.split("[:+]"), but I actually need a whitespace in the array between test3 and test4. I will update my question with the wanted output to clearify it!

Comment: Nice. I will also try out your solution since I can imagine that both approaches differ in performance. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Adarsh, I didn't mention the case in my question, but: if ++ appears at the end of the string I also need a whitespace for it. Right now only the approach from anubhava returns a whitespace in that case. Thought I should add this info.